# want output of “14120000” as “14.12 million” in asp classic

Tags: function, asp-classic

My code is in asp classic. i am not getting where i went wrong. can you guys please help me out.

```
    <%
response.write("Hi")
response.end()
    function nicenumber(n) 
        n = (replace(",","",n))

        if(!IsNumeric(n)) then
        nicenumber = false
        end if
        if(n>1000000000000) then 
        nicenumber = round((n/1000000000000),2) & " trillion"
        else if(n>1000000000) then 
        nicenumber = round((n/1000000000),2) & " billion"
        else if(n>1000000) then
        nicenumber = round((n/1000000),2) & " million"
        else if(n>1000) then
        nicenumber = round((n/1000),2) & " thousand"
        end if
        nicenumber = number_format(n)

    End function

response.write(nicenumber("14120000")) '14.12 million

%>
```

input :- 14120000 
output required :- 14.12 million
want output of  “14120000” as “14.12 million” in asp classic

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Is this (supposed to be) jscript or vbscript? ("Classic ASP" can use either). Because vbscript doesn't use `return`; you should use `nice_number = foo` instead of `return foo`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7hbf8fa(v=vs.84).aspx). Other than that: you should state your problem clearly. What are you *expecting* to happen, what happens *actually* etc.

Comment: @RobIII Regardless of the language (VBscript or Javascript) there are a catalog of errors in the function. Javascript doesn't contain `round` or `is_numeric` functions (as listed), it's also missing line terminators.

If it's vbscript, the function syntax is wrong (vbscript doesn't use curly braces). Also the `return` command as you pointed out.

Comment: its asp classic . please suggest me any other option

Comment: `its asp classic`: ASP classic doesn't clarify if you're useing VBScript or JScript; both are an option in ASP classic. `please suggest me any other option`: What other option? You need to write correct code... Your question initially contained a mixture of JScript and VBScript and won't work. Then, you editted your question so much that now the current comments don't make sense. Again: tell us what happens, what error(s) you get, etc. Here's a hint: `!` is no operator in VBScript but JScript. You need to use `not` for VBScript. Also you left out an `end if`.

Comment: ...Also you're calling `nice_number` with a `string` argument instead of an integer/long, there's no `number_format` function in VBScript (it's [`FormatNumber`](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatnumber.asp) instead) and the [`replace function`](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_replace.asp) is passed the arguments in an incorrect order. The `else if` should be `elseif`'s etc.

Comment: @RobIII: This is obviously VB Script; if it was JScript the `If` statements would look similar to JavaScript: `if(condition) {...} else {...}`. @user3156561: Put the language specification at the start of a script file like so: `<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>`.

Comment: @Westie: It is **now** "obviously" VBScript, the original question was a mixture of both (see the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21428449/revisions)). Hence: "*Your question initially contained a mixture of JScript and VBScript and won't work. Then, you editted your question so much that now the current comments don't make sense.*"

Comment: @RobIII: Ah!  My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've explained most of your mistakes [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428449/want-output-of-14120000-as-14-12-million-in-asp-classic/21430032#comment32329126_21428449) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428449/want-output-of-14120000-as-14-12-million-in-asp-classic/21430032#comment32330852_21428449) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428449/want-output-of-14120000-as-14-12-million-in-asp-classic/21430032#comment32331072_21428449) to your question; for the rest. Here is the code. Enjoy.

```
<%
function NiceNumber(n) 
        n = replace(n, ",","")

        if(not IsNumeric(n)) then
            NiceNumber = false
        elseif (n>=1e12) then 
            NiceNumber = FormatNumber((n/1e12),2) & " trillion"
        elseif(n>=1e9) then 
            NiceNumber = FormatNumber((n/1e9),2) & " billion"
        elseif(n>=1e6) then
            NiceNumber = FormatNumber((n/1e6),2) & " million"
        elseif(n>=1e3) then
            NiceNumber = FormatNumber((n/1e3),2) & " thousand"
        else
            NiceNumber = FormatNumber(n)
        end if
End function

SetLocale(1033) 'EN-US  (1043 = NL-NL for example)
x = "1234567890123456789"
For i = 1 to len(x)
    response.write(Left(x, i) & " &raquo; " & NiceNumber(Left(x, i))) & "<br>"
Next
%>
```

Output (using 1033 (EN-US) [locale](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_setlocale.asp)):

```
1 » 1.00
12 » 12.00
123 » 123.00
1234 » 1.23 thousand
12345 » 12.35 thousand
123456 » 123.46 thousand
1234567 » 1.23 million
12345678 » 12.35 million
123456789 » 123.46 million
1234567890 » 1.23 billion
12345678901 » 12.35 billion
123456789012 » 123.46 billion
1234567890123 » 1.23 trillion
12345678901234 » 12.35 trillion
123456789012345 » 123.46 trillion
1234567890123456 » 1,234.57 trillion
12345678901234567 » 12,345.68 trillion
123456789012345678 » 123,456.79 trillion
1234567890123456789 » 1,234,567.89 trillion
```

Lookup [FormatNumber](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatnumber.asp) for more formatting options.

Comment: You need to think again about the way you convert `n` at the beginning. You'll get an error if `n` is not already numeric.

Comment: Thanks you in the name of all the developers who still prefer classic asp sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ language="vbscript" %>
<%



Set cd = CreateObject("ChartDirector.API")


'Data for the chart as 3 random data series

'response.Write("Hi")
Set r = cd.RanSeries(127)
response.Write("HI")
data0 = r.getSeries(100, 100, -15, 15)
data1 = r.getSeries(100, 150, -15, 15)
data2 = r.getSeries(100, 200, -15, 15)

timeStamps = r.getDateSeries(100, DateSerial(2011, 1, 1), 86400)

' Create a XYChart object of size 640 x 400 pixels
Set c = cd.XYChart(640, 400)

' Add a title to the chart using 18 pts Times New Roman Bold Italic font
Call c.addTitle("Product Line Global Revenue", "timesbi.ttf", 18)

' Set the plotarea at (50, 55) with width 70 pixels less than chart width, and height 90 pixels less
' than chart height. Use a vertical gradient from light blue (f0f6ff) to sky blue (a0c0ff) as
' background. Set border to transparent and grid lines to white (ffffff).
Call c.setPlotArea(50, 55, c.getWidth() - 70, c.getHeight() - 90, c.linearGradientColor(0, 55, 0, _
     c.getHeight() - 35, &Hf0f6ff, &Ha0c0ff), -1, cd.Transparent, &Hffffff, &Hffffff)

' Add a legend box at (50, 25) using horizontal layout. Use 10pts Arial Bold as font. Set the
' background and border color to Transparent.
Call c.addLegend(50, 25, False, "arialbd.ttf", 10).setBackground(cd.Transparent)

' Set axis label style to 8pts Arial Bold
Call c.xAxis().setLabelStyle("arialbd.ttf", 8)
Call c.yAxis().setLabelStyle("arialbd.ttf", 8)

' Set the axis stem to transparent
Call c.xAxis().setColors(cd.Transparent)
Call c.yAxis().setColors(cd.Transparent)

' Configure x-axis label format
Call c.xAxis().setMultiFormat(cd.StartOfYearFilter(), "{value|mm/yyyy} ", cd.StartOfMonthFilter(), _
    "{value|mm}")

' Add axis title using 10pts Arial Bold Italic font
Call c.yAxis().setTitle("USD millions", "arialbi.ttf", 10)

' Add a line layer to the chart using a line width of 2 pixels.
Set layer = c.addLineLayer2()
Call layer.setLineWidth(2)

' Add 3 data series to the line layer
Call layer.setXData(timeStamps)
Call layer.addDataSet(data0, &Hff3333, "Alpha")
Call layer.addDataSet(data1, &H008800, "Beta")
Call layer.addDataSet(data2, &H3333cc, "Gamma")

' Create the WebChartViewer object
Set viewer = cd.WebChartViewer(Request, "chart1")

' Output the chart
chartQuery = c.makeSession(Session, viewer.Id)

' Set the chart URL to the viewer
viewer.ImageUrl = "getchart.asp?" & chartQuery

' Output Javascript chart model to the browser to support tracking cursor
viewer.ChartModel = c.getJsChartModel()
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Track Line with Data Labels</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cdjcv.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin:5px 0px 0px 5px">
<script type="text/javascript">

//
// Use the window load event to set up the MouseMovePlotArea event handler
//
JsChartViewer.addEventListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var viewer = JsChartViewer.get('<%=viewer.Id%>');

    // Draw track cursor when mouse is moving over plotarea. Hide it when mouse leaves plot area.
    viewer.attachHandler("MouseMovePlotArea", function(e) {
        trackLineLabel(viewer, viewer.getPlotAreaMouseX());
        viewer.setAutoHide("all", "MouseOutPlotArea");
    });
});

//
// Draw track line with data labels
//
function trackLineLabel(viewer, mouseX)
{
    // Remove all previously drawn tracking object
    viewer.hideObj("all");

    // The chart and its plot area
    var c = viewer.getChart();
    var plotArea = c.getPlotArea();

    // Get the data x-value that is nearest to the mouse, and find its pixel coordinate.
    var xValue = c.getNearestXValue(mouseX);
    var xCoor = c.getXCoor(xValue);

    // Draw a vertical track line at the x-position
    viewer.drawVLine("trackLine", xCoor, plotArea.getTopY(), plotArea.getBottomY(), "black 1px dotted");

    // Draw a label on the x-axis to show the track line position
    viewer.showTextBox("xAxisLabel", xCoor, plotArea.getBottomY() + 4, JsChartViewer.Top,
        c.xAxis().getFormattedLabel(xValue, "mmm dd, yyyy"),
        "font:bold 11px Arial;color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#000000;padding:0px 3px");

    // Iterate through all layers to draw the data labels
    for (var i = 0; i < c.getLayerCount(); ++i)
    {
        var layer = c.getLayerByZ(i);

        // The data array index of the x-value
        var xIndex = layer.getXIndexOf(xValue);

        // Iterate through all the data sets in the layer
        for (var j = 0; j < layer.getDataSetCount(); ++j)
        {
            var dataSet = layer.getDataSetByZ(j);

            // Get the color and position of the data label
            var color = dataSet.getDataColor();
            var yCoor = c.getYCoor(dataSet.getPosition(xIndex), dataSet.getUseYAxis());

            // Draw a track dot with a label next to it for visible data points in the plot area
            if ((yCoor != null) && (yCoor >= plotArea.getTopY()) && (yCoor <= plotArea.getBottomY()) &&
                (color != null))
            {
                viewer.showTextBox("dataPoint" + i + "_" + j, xCoor, yCoor, JsChartViewer.Center,
                    viewer.htmlRect(7, 7, color));

                viewer.showTextBox("dataLabel" + i + "_" + j, xCoor + 5, yCoor, JsChartViewer.Left,
                    dataSet.getValue(xIndex).toPrecision(4),
                    "padding:0px 3px;font:bold 10px Arial;background-color:" + color + ";color:#FFFFFF");
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
<div style="font-size:18pt; font-family:verdana; font-weight:bold">
    Track Line with Data Labels
</div>
<hr style="border:solid 1px #000080" />
<div style="font-size:10pt; font-family:verdana; margin-bottom:1.5em">
    <a href="viewsource.asp?file=<%=Request("SCRIPT_NAME")%>">View Source Code</a>
</div>
<!-- ****** Here is the chart image ****** -->
<%=viewer.renderHTML()%>

</body>
</html>
```